# JavaScript How to run variables in if and for?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I want to use FOR loop instead, please.

```
let int1, int1, int3;//... (int4 to int999)
let op1, op;//... (op2 to op999)
if(int1 < 200) {
    op1 = int1;
}
else {
    op1 = '';
}
if(int2 < 200) {... (same IF statement for int2 to int999)
```

Instead, I want this.

```
for(i = 1; i < 5; i++) {                
    let int = [int1, int2, int3, int4];
    let op = [op1, op2, op3, op4];
    if(int[i] < 200) {
        op[i] = int[i];
    }
    else {
        op[i] = '';
    }
}
alert(op1 + op2 + op3 + op4);
```

But that doesn't work somebody help.

Comment: Let input be an array `let input = [input1, input2, ...];`

Comment: Any time you find yourself using variables with sequential names like that, you almost always should be using an array instead.

Comment: I updated the code but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be as follows with an example:

```
let int = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let op = [999, 999, 999, 999];

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                
    if(int[i] < 200) {
        op[i] = int[i];
    }
    else {
        op[i] = '';
    }
}
alert(op[0] + op[1] + op[2] + op[3]);
```

**Out:**

```
285
```

Or in your kind of "symbolic form":

```
let int = [int1, int2, int3, int4];
let op = [op1, op2, op3, op4];

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                
    if(int[i] < 200) {
        op[i] = int[i];
    }
    else {
        op[i] = 0;
    }
}
alert(op[0] + op[1] + op[2] + op[3]);
```

Comment: close but op1 isn't being added because its undefined somehow

Comment: @LiquidiceSlayer to solve on the mystery you have to provide me the actual values of op1 to op4 and int1 to int4 and I answer the rests. Because as you can see with a real example data it works.

Comment: op1-4 can be whatever you want(input: 3, 4, 2, 5 but output 425)

Comment: if int1-5 is 12345, the code outputs 2345 (op5 is in for some reason while op1 is left out)

Comment: The problem is solved if int[i] is replaced with int[i-1]. However, that doesn't seem elegant.

Comment: @LiquidiceSlayer That's where your problem is solved. Since javascript indexing from 0.

Comment: Okay, the new problem is that op1-999 isn't being saved. It alerts correctly but afterward, op1-999 becomes undefined and it can't be used in another function.

Comment: I solved this by doing op1 = op[0] however, for op1-999, is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a set of variables, You should use an array instead.
Then, Your code would look something like this:

```
let input = [input1, input2 ... input999];
let output = [];
for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if(input[i]) {
        output[i] = input[i];
    } else {
        alert("error")
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm only allowed if while and for.

Comment: Int doesn't get transfered to op.

Comment: Have you filled the input array with actual data ?